# How to get an unknown word before a known one with Regex in PHP

Tags: php, regex, cpu-word, preg-match-all

I have this text:

```
andres wins Pot (9.50) with a Full House
```

and i want to get the word "andres". This is a player name (variable), that is always shown before the word "wins".

I need to use preg_match_all function, and i am trying with:

```
%(?:\S+\s)?\S*wins%
```

But it returns me:

```
andres wins
```

I need only, andres.

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a capturing group instead of a non-capturing group. This should be enough to match the preceding word.

```
(\w+)\s*wins
```

You need to reference `$matches[1]` to return your match result.

Comment: Hello ! thanks, but im getting:
Array
(
    [0] => andres wins
    [1] => andres
)
I just need andres

Answer (score 0):

```
(\w+)(?=\s*wins)
```

You can also use this.Grab the match[1].This will not capture anything else.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/xO7bK2/1